# java - does GC try more then once to release memory?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, garbage-collection

Lets say i have a asyncTask like this:

```
 public void startAsyncTask() {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(300000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
                return null;
            }
        }.execute();
    }
```

For those who dont know a asyncTask just creates a background thread.
and anonymous classes are really non-static inner classes.

Now lets say in the activity (main thread)  i call `startAsyncTask()`

the thread will take a little while to complete (about 5 minutes).

During the background threads lifetime, lets imagine the activity gets **destroyed** and its time to garbage collect the activity.  Since the asyncTask has an implicit reference to the outer class (the activity) the activity will leak and will not be garbage collected.

But my question is the following:  After some time, the child thread will eventually finish. Can the GC attempt to free memory again or is the activity forever leaked ? What i want to know really is if the child thread finishes in a reasonable amount of time will the activities memory be freed or is it only on the first attempt the GC tries and after that attempt the memory is forever lost ?

Comment: *let's imagine at least a few minute for this example* then obviously `AsyncTask` is a bad choice

Comment: GC will try to do his best no matter what and this transcends the technology used (.NET, java, and all technologies that use generation-based GC algorithms / mark and sweep algorithms). generally, you just have to be sure that you don't hang references in static variables and you will be fine, GC algorithm does the rest for you. Have you noticed a memory leak? I am sure that you can overcome it by making a reference equal to null (the async task for example that might hold closure references to other objects). I come from .NET world but i am sure that in java it's almost the same.

Comment: Hopefully yes it will try again as long as your instance is being hard referenced elsewhere it will only change of location over time Eden -> Survivor -> Tenured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The garbage collector does not operate based on the activity life-cycle, it operates based on "are there any objects referencing it". So yeah, the activity memory will be freed after the thread finishes (and the AsyncTask is not referencing it anymore).

But that still is a memory leak of a very heavy object (the activity). And it's bad programming that shouldn't be done.

I'm not sure if you have an actual problem that you want to apply that, or is that a purely theoretical question on the inner workins of the VM, but if it's an actual problem that you want to apply that; the answer is: **Don't do it!**

Comment: in that case, why are so many android programmers bothered by asyncTasks holding a reference to the activity.  I mean eventually the asyncTasks will end and the activities memory will be released. so i mean as long as the asyncTask is not alive too long holding a reference to outer class shouldn't be too bad, correct ?

Comment: @j2emanue sorry but no. I honestly don't understand why Google didn't deprecated this class and apologize for it already. Activity is a HUGE object running on a tiny battery powered, memory constrained processor. It should not leave any second longer than after onDestroy()